# perl - exclusion of some line from file

Tags: perl

I wrote a short script to convert my data (from input file to output). I stopped, when I should extract only these lines with negatove energy (the last value in each lines).

My input data is that:

```
ATOM    367  OH2 HOH   367      -2.010   7.370  -7.369   -6.52
ATOM    491  OH2 HOH   491       0.990   8.370  -8.369   -2.24
ATOM    652  OH2 HOH   652       5.490  -6.130   2.631    2.98
ATOM    689  OH2 HOH   689       6.490 -15.130   8.631   -4.23
ATOM    738  OH2 HOH   738       7.490  19.870  -8.369    3.38
ATOM    793  OH2 HOH   793       8.990  -2.630 -22.869   -2.29
ATOM    857  OH2 HOH   857      10.490  13.370  -5.869   -1.31
.
.
.
```

My output data looks like:

```
    moja woda t=   0 
        1
        1SOL     OW    1  -0.344   0.437   0.633  -9.290
     20.0 20.0 20.0
    moja woda t=   1 
        1
        1SOL     OW    1  -0.194   0.537  -0.767  -2.990
     20.0 20.0 20.0
    moja woda t=   2 
        1
        1SOL     OW    1  -0.044   0.287   0.333   4.960
     20.0 20.0 20.0
    moja woda t=   3 
        1
        1SOL     OW    1   0.106   0.837  -0.817  -1.300
     20.0 20.0 20.0
    moja woda t=   4 
    .
    .
    .
```

My script is:

```
!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $list=$ARGV[0];


open(LST,$list) or die;

my $time=0;

my @id_table;
my @nr_table;

open(GRO,">waters.gro") or die;

while(<LST>) {
  my $pdb_file=$_;
  chomp $pdb_file;
  my $pdb_id=substr $pdb_file,0,4;
  open(PDB,$pdb_file) or die;
  while(<PDB>) {
      my $line=$_;
      my $x=substr $line,30,8;
      my $y=substr $line,38,8;
      my $z=substr $line,46,8;
      my $en=substr $line,54,8;
      my $w_id=substr $line,23,3;
      print GRO "moja woda t=   $time \n";
      printf(GRO "%5d\n",1);
      printf(GRO "    1SOL     OW    1%8.3f%8.3f%8.3f%8.3f\n",$x/10.0,$y/10.0,$z/10.0,$en);
      print GRO " 20.0 20.0 20.0\n";
      $id_table[$time]=$pdb_id;
      $nr_table[$time]=$w_id;
      $time++;
  }
  close PDB;
}
close GRO;
```

I'd like to convert only these lines where the energy value is less than 0 (the last column). How exactly I should do it?

Thank you in advance, 
M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to extract the values based on specific locations in the string, I would use the `split` function to split each row into an array.

replace this:

```
my $x=substr $line,30,8;
my $y=substr $line,38,8;
my $z=substr $line,46,8;
my $en=substr $line,54,8;
my $w_id=substr $line,23,3;
```

with this:

```
my ($w_id, $x, $y, $z, $en) = (split(/\s+/, $line))[1, 5, 6, 7, 8];
next if $en >= 0;
```

That should be enough to get the output you want.

What is it doing?

`my @array = split(/\s+/, $line)` tells perl to split the string into a list. The `/\s+/` is a regular expression that tells the `split` function to split around one or more whitespace characters.

`@array` will contain 9 entires, one for each column of your data. Since you are not using all the columns, I used an array slice to extract only the entries you are interested in. For example `my ($zero, $one, $three) = (@array)[0, 1, 3]` extracts the elements at indexes 0, 1, and 3 of @array and puts them into variables $zero, $one, and $three respectively.

The `next if $en > 0;` line tells the script to skip the rest of the current iteration of the loop if the value of `$en` is positive.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem! In your new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34799244/perl-sort-numbers-in-column-in-order it looks like you used this answer. It would make me happy if you accepted the answer you actually used. ;-)

Comment: I accepted :) At first, I don't know for what is this thick :) Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

OK, for starters - don't use `substr` for this, that's nasty. Try `split`.

And then you can just 'test' the field value. This is a cut down example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @nr_table;
my @id_table;

while ( <DATA> ) {

    my @fields = split; 
    my ( $pdb_id, $w_id )  = @fields[0,1];

    if ( $fields[8] < 0 ) {
       print  "moja woda t=   ",scalar @id_table, "\n";
       printf( "%5d\n",1);
       printf( "    1SOL     OW    1%8.3f%8.3f%8.3f%8.3f\n", map { $_ / 10.0 } @fields[5..7], $fields[8]);
       print  " 20.0 20.0 20.0\n";
    }
    push ( @id_table, $pdb_id ); 
    push ( @nr_table, $w_id ); 
}

__DATA__
ATOM    367  OH2 HOH   367      -2.010   7.370  -7.369   -6.52
ATOM    491  OH2 HOH   491       0.990   8.370  -8.369   -2.24
ATOM    652  OH2 HOH   652       5.490  -6.130   2.631    2.98
ATOM    689  OH2 HOH   689       6.490 -15.130   8.631   -4.23
ATOM    738  OH2 HOH   738       7.490  19.870  -8.369    3.38
ATOM    793  OH2 HOH   793       8.990  -2.630 -22.869   -2.29
ATOM    857  OH2 HOH   857      10.490  13.370  -5.869   -1.31
```

Note - by default `split` acts on `$_` - the current line, and splits on 'any whitespace'.

You can move the `push` statements inside the condition if desired.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: How could I sort the numbers in $en column? Should I create a temporary array by map or without?

Comment: You could, but that's a slightly different question - this solution as above just works line by line in the file. To sort, you'd need to read the whole thing into an array (of arrays). Doable, but I would suggest worth another question rather than trying to explain here.

Comment: Sobrique! Thank you again, I'll ask for a moment! Enjoy your day!