# perl: sort numbers in column in order

Tags: perl, sorting

I'd like to sort my numbers in the last column, $en in reverse order (from the smallest to the greater value). More, I specified my numbers. They reach 0 and be only negative.

My script is following:

```
!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $list=$ARGV[0];


open(LST,$list) or die;

my $time=0;

my @id_table;
my @nr_table;
my @energy;

open(GRO,">waters.gro") or die;

while(<LST>) {
  my $pdb_file=$_;
  chomp $pdb_file;
  my $pdb_id=substr $pdb_file,0,4;
  open(PDB,$pdb_file) or die;
  while(<PDB>) {
      my $line=$_;
      my ($w_id, $x, $y, $z, $en) = (split(/\s+/, $line))[1, 5, 6, 7, 8];
      next if $en >= 0;
      my @energy = sort {$b <=> $a} $en;
      print GRO "moja woda t=   $time \n";
      printf(GRO "%5d\n",1);
      printf(GRO "    1SOL     OW    1%8.3f%8.3f%8.3f%8.3f\n",$x/10.0,$y/10.0,$z/10.0,$en);
      print GRO " 20.0 20.0 20.0\n";
      $id_table[$time]=$pdb_id;
      $nr_table[$time]=$w_id;
      $time++;
  }
  close PDB;
}
close GRO;
```

Unfortunately, my idea for sorting doeasn't work. I am a beginner in Perls' scripting. In my output I'd like to order values in increasing order.

Thank you in advance.
Marta

my input file:

```
ATOM    367  OH2 HOH   367      -2.010   7.370  -7.369   -6.52
ATOM    491  OH2 HOH   491       0.990   8.370  -8.369   -2.24
ATOM    652  OH2 HOH   652       5.490  -6.130   2.631    2.98
ATOM    689  OH2 HOH   689       6.490 -15.130   8.631   -4.23
ATOM    738  OH2 HOH   738       7.490  19.870  -8.369    3.38
ATOM    793  OH2 HOH   793       8.990  -2.630 -22.869   -2.29
ATOM    857  OH2 HOH   857      10.490  13.370  -5.869   -1.31
.
.
.
```

After action I got output (without the sort line):

```
moja woda t=   0 
        1
        1SOL     OW    1  -0.344   0.437   0.633  -9.290
     20.0 20.0 20.0
    moja woda t=   1 
        1
        1SOL     OW    1  -0.194   0.537  -0.767  -2.990
     20.0 20.0 20.0
    moja woda t=   2 
        1
        1SOL     OW    1  -0.044   0.287   0.333   4.960
     20.0 20.0 20.0
    moja woda t=   3 
        1
        1SOL     OW    1   0.106   0.837  -0.817  -1.300
     20.0 20.0 20.0
    moja woda t=   4 
    .
    .
    .
```

I'd like to order my data (for each line, which depend on $en column) in order. I think I should create a new array, but I don't know how exactly and where exactly I should put the sort in script.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "it doesn't work"?

Comment: @AKHolland If you look at the code, the OP's problem becomes quite obvious: `my @energy = sort {$b <=> $a} $en;` (You're right, though, they should absolutely be more specific.)

Comment: Do you want the lines sorted across the whole of the output, or within the data from each file in the list file?

Comment: FWIW, smallest to largest would be ascending sort order, which is the default. Reverse order would be a descending sort, or largest to smallest.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] for this question (i.e., include sample data) and [edit] your post. It's much easier to help you solve your problem if you help us not have to pull sample data out of our... uhh... ears.

Comment: We basically need a few lines from one of the "PDB" files (on which the innermost loop operates).

Comment: I edited my question to let you know my problem. If sth is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: the input file is a fragment of pdb_file.

Comment: So, are you trying to sort the output per file, or overall?

Comment: Per file - it was my first thought, but the easiest way is more desirable.

Comment: And (roughly) how big is each file?

Comment: It depend ( i have a series of pdb_files) from 15 lines to 120 lines of data such as input file below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code that I've altered

The reason your sort isn't working is that the statement

```
my @energy = sort {$b <=> $a} $en
```

sorts *just* the value of `$en` and puts it into `@energy`. With just one value there's clearly nothing to do. You have to have *all* of the data you want to sort available at once

As long as your files are reasonably sized, the usual way to do this is to read the file into an array with one record per element, and then sort that array. I've done that in the program below. Each element of the array `@pdb_data` contains a reference to an array of five fields in the order you originally had them

The `$time` value added as a sixth field on each record, because this must be done before sorting. Finally the array is sorted in increasing order of `$en` — the fifth field. (By the way, the standard sort order is from smaller values to bigger ones. It is a normal sort that you want, not a reversed one.)

Te data in the array which has been filtered and sorted can then be printed in a simple `for` loop. The assignment

```
my ( $w_id, $x, $y, $z, $en, $time ) =  @$_
```

pulls the fields from each array element just as they were originally with the addition of a time field at the end

I've been unable to test this without any data, but the program does compile

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my ($list_file) = @ARGV;

open my $lst_fh, '<', $list_file or die qq{Unable to open "$list_file" for input: $!};

my $gro_file = 'waters.gro';
open my $gro_fh, '>', $gro_file or die qq{Unable to open "$gro_file" for input: $!};

while ( my $pdb_file = <$lst_fh> ) {

    chomp $pdb_file;
    open my $pdb_fh, '<', $pdb_file or die $!;

    my @pdb_data;
    my $time = 0;

    while ( <$pdb_fh> ) {

        my @record = ( split )[ 1, 5, 6, 7, 8 ];

        next unless $record[4] < 0;

        push @record, $time++;

        push @pdb_data, \@record;
    }

    @pdb_data = sort { $a->[4] <=> $b->[4] } @pdb_data;

    my $stdout = select $gro_fh;

    for ( @pdb_data ) {

        my ( $w_id, $x, $y, $z, $en, $time ) =  @$_;

        printf "moja woda t=   %d\n", $time;
        printf "%5d\n", 1;
        printf "    1SOL     OW    1%8.3f%8.3f%8.3f%8.3f\n", $x/10.0, $y/10.0, $z/10.0, $en;
        print  " 20.0 20.0 20.0\n";
    }

    select $stdout;
}

close $gro_fh or die $!;
```

---

### Update

This variation reads all of the data from all files in the list file before sorting and printing it. The time value is applied in the order of the `$ne` field

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my ($list_file) = @ARGV;
my $gro_file = 'waters.gro';

open my $lst_fh, '<', $list_file or die qq{Unable to open "$list_file" for input: $!};

my @pdb_data;

while ( my $pdb_file = <$lst_fh> ) {

    chomp $pdb_file;
    open my $pdb_fh, '<', $pdb_file or die $!;

    while ( <$pdb_fh> ) {

        my @record = ( split )[ 1, 5, 6, 7, 8 ];

        next unless $record[4] < 0;

        push @pdb_data, \@record;
    }
}


@pdb_data = sort { $a->[4] <=> $b->[4] } @pdb_data;

open my $gro_fh, '>', $gro_file or die qq{Unable to open "$gro_file" for input: $!};
select $gro_fh;

my $time = 0;

for ( @pdb_data ) {

    my ( $w_id, $x, $y, $z, $en ) =  @$_;

    printf "moja woda t=   %d\n", $time++;
    printf "%5d\n", 1;
    printf "    1SOL     OW    1%8.3f%8.3f%8.3f%8.3f\n", $x/10.0, $y/10.0, $z/10.0, $en;
    print  " 20.0 20.0 20.0\n";
}

close or die $!;
```

### output

```
moja woda t=   0
    1
    1SOL     OW    1  -0.201   0.737  -0.737  -6.520
 20.0 20.0 20.0
moja woda t=   1
    1
    1SOL     OW    1   0.649  -1.513   0.863  -4.230
 20.0 20.0 20.0
moja woda t=   2
    1
    1SOL     OW    1   0.899  -0.263  -2.287  -2.290
 20.0 20.0 20.0
moja woda t=   3
    1
    1SOL     OW    1   0.099   0.837  -0.837  -2.240
 20.0 20.0 20.0
moja woda t=   4
    1
    1SOL     OW    1   1.049   1.337  -0.587  -1.310
 20.0 20.0 20.0
```

Comment: My list file has got a few pdb files (roughly 5-120 files - it depend on series) and each pdb file consist of few data line. I'd like to do sort for overall (one series of pdb_file from list file).

Comment: Thank you so much for response!

Comment: @MartaWisniewska: Okay, so what do you want to happen to the *time* field? Should it keep increasing across all the files, or should it reset to zero for each one?

Comment: OK. I'd like to sor $en column in icreasing order till it achieve 0, then stop to print data, For _time=_ lines I'd like to number it from 0 till sth. (for the smallest $en value _time=0_ , in next $en value  _time=1_.